# How to swap Spring Boot mapper from Jackson to kotlinx.serialization

Tags: spring-boot, kotlinx.serialization

I would like my Spring Boot project to use kotlinx.serialization.  I can't figure out how to swap the mapper correctly... If I wanted to use GSON, I could just note it in the props via spring.http.converters.preferred-json-mapper=gson.

Has anyone had success with this?

Answer (score 6):

Just use Spring >= 5.3 and add corresponding kotlin plugin and serialization dependency. Spring switches serialization automatically. [Details](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/languages.html#kotlin-multiplatform-serialization)